# IndexError: list index out of range when changing value in a row by text value in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the data in a column in my dataFrame from number to text but So far my solution are not working.

exemple

```
# Save results and compute score of probabilities...
     id  ... categorie_fmc
0     5  ...             1
1     7  ...             1
2    11  ...             1
3    12  ...             1
4    17  ...             0
```

What I tried :

```
finalFile = pd.DataFrame(liste, columns=['id', 'participant','sent','categorie_fmc'])
    
# view DataFrame
print(finalFile)
    
# replace
labels = ['Frein', 'Motivation' 'condition']
finalFile['categorie_fmc'] = np.where(finalFile['categorie_fmc'] == 0, labels[0], finalFile['categorie_fmc'])
finalFile['categorie_fmc'] = np.where(finalFile['categorie_fmc'] == 1, labels[1], finalFile['categorie_fmc'])
finalFile['categorie_fmc'] = np.where(finalFile['categorie_fmc'] == 2, labels[2], finalFile['categorie_fmc'])
```

But it is not working , getting this error :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
finalFile['categorie_fmc'] = np.where(finalFile['categorie_fmc'] == 2, labels[2], finalFile['categorie_fmc'])
IndexError: list index out of range
srun: error: r14i5n2: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
srun: Terminating job step 519075.0
```

What I expected :

```
# Save results and compute score of probabilities...
     id  ... categorie_fmc
0     5  ...             Motivation
1     7  ...             Motivation
2    11  ...             Motivation
3    12  ...             Motivation
4    17  ...             Frein
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `map` function:

```
finalFile['categorie_fmc'] = finalFile['categorie_fmc'].map({0: 'Frein', 1: 'Motivation', 2: 'condition'})
```